# Language problem - Google Fitness API Scopes

Tags: google-api, google-fit, google-fitness-api

I´m creating an app which needs user authorization to access to some private health information about Google Fit app. When adding the scopes in the OAuth consent screen I can see some Fit scopes are not correctly translated into my language (in my case spanish). These are, for example: fitness.blood_glucose.read, fitness.blood_pressure.read...

If I change the language in the URL with the parameter hl=de, hl=es... I can see that only some of the scopes change correctly the language. Can I do something in order to change the language of every scope? Is this a Google problem or mine? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended. On the consent screen or login screen, there is a section in the lower right corner that allows you to select the language.

Comment: Not really. Even if you select the language in the lower right corner, some scopes don´t change their text. For example, if I select Spanish, the blood pressure read scope is still in English: "See info about your blood pressure in Google Fit. I consent to Google sharing my blood pressure information with this app..."